# Configure oncall rotation with zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Is it possible to create a rotation of on call personal with Zabbix.

What I want to archive is that emails with issues only go to a specific person during one week, and that change automatically when the we ends.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can not be done with the built-in capabilities. You would have to use external scripts as Zabbix alertscripts, or script things using the Zabbix API.

Comment: I was suspecting that but just wanted some confirmation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request in Zabbix to do exactly this.

https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-537

Until then, you could take a look at "iLert" or "OpsGenie"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31758016)